# How do I make rails recognize a correct id of an active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a board which consists of "post" model and "comment" model.

The board I'm making doesn't need signing-in procedure, so the password is needed for a deletion of a post or a comment.

When I am trying to delete a post, the code below works well.
(If a user click the "Delete" button, the hidden DIV which has a password form appears, so I used form_for.)

```
<%= link_to_function "Delete", "$('#post_password_box').toggle()" %> |
<div id="post_password_box">
  <%= form_for(@post, url: { action: "destroy"}, html: { method: :delete, class: nil, id: nil}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %><br>

    <%= f.submit "Commit", class: "btn", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
    <%= button_to_function "Cancel", "$('#post_password_box').hide()", class: "btn" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So, I used the similar code when it comes to delete the comment.

```
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li class="author"><%= comment.author %></li>
    <li class="content"><%= comment.content %></li>
    <li class="date"><%= comment.created_at.localtime.strftime("%r") %></li>
    <li class="button">
      <%= link_to_function "X", "$(this).next().toggle()" %>
      <div class="comment_password_box">
        <%= form_for(comment, url: {controller: "comments", action: "destroy"}, html: {method: :delete, class: nil, id: nil}) do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password %>

          <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

At a glance, The code above seems to work well, but there is a problem that the code doesn't delete a proper comment.

For example, if the id of a post is 20 and the id of a comment I want to delete is 10, it deletes the comment whose id is 20.

And I found the problem comes from the fact that the form tag's action attributes is like below in every comment.

```
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments/20" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Y2oBuoIxa+9yPLC5WflKVVELw3jgKsi9s9/8Cfvr2u8=" /></div>
```

What should I do to make rails find the proper form tag's action attribute's value? (In this case, it should be "/comments/10", instead of "/comments/20".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let rails generate the URL for you. At the moment you're setting the URL yourself but you're not specifying a value for `:id` so rails takes the current value of `params[:id]`

Try

```
form_for(comment, :method => :delete)
```

Instead.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! :) It helped a lot.